# Java error ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, sqlite, kotlin

I am working on an app that allows me to search for a file inside the device with the open file manager, and then save the data in Sqlite. First I have a button that looks for the .txt files.

```
Local.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        buscarArchivo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                        buscarArchivo.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        buscarArchivo.setType("text/*");
                        startActivityForResult(buscarArchivo, 10);
                    }
                });
```

I get the path of the file and then send it to the method readFile () that is responsible for locating the file and storing the data

```
     Uri uri = data.getData();
     String path = uri.getPath();
     path = path.substring(path.indexOf(":") + 1);

     String[] texto = leerArchivo(path);
```

method that receives the path and is responsible for reading the file

```
private String[] leerArchivo(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            int i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString().split("\n");
    }
```

But at the time of running the application and selecting a file it is generating the following error

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Probando.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
```

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear itself - The program is not finding such file on that path

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the path is correct? Maybe this line

```
path = path.substring(path.indexOf(":") + 1);
```

is not refleting actual path. Try using directly the absolute path, to check if the error persists.